# Как реализовать иллюзию непрерывного движения в SVG?

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Представьте себе индикатор прогресса, подобный этому, который создает ощущение движения влево:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание: тонкая ярко-зеленая линия в верхней части анимации является артефактом сжатия.

Я ищу способ реализовать нечто подобное, но в произвольном пути SVG, например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь понять, что там на самом деле происходит, например:

- Это градиент с большим количеством `stops`, и они продолжают
  двигаться?
- Эти много смежных, перекошенных прямоугольников движутся в унисон?
- Это одна длинная последовательность наклонных соседних
  прямоугольников, вдоль которых движется «скользящее окно»?

Как можно реализовать такие анимации?
И что было бы наилучшей практикой для его реализации с использованием примитивов SVG?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to implement a continuous motion illusion in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56159021/7394871) от участника  [@ralien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27342/ralien).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56159021/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Я использую путь дважды: #a и #b. Оба пути #a, и #b имеют `stroke-dasharray: 1`, но путь с id  `#b`   имеет смещение `stroke-dashoffset: 1;`

Я анимирую `stroke-dashoffset` для обоих `#a` и `#b`.

```css
use {
  stroke-dasharray: 1;
}
#a {
  stroke: green;
  animation: dasha 5s linear infinite;
}
#b {
  stroke: DarkSeaGreen;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  animation: dashb 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes dasha {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -54.66;
  }
}
@keyframes dashb {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -53.66;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24' width="200"><title>gesture</title>
    <defs><path id="thePath"  fill="none" d='M4.59 6.89c.7-.71 1.4-1.35 1.71-1.22.5.2 0 1.03-.3 1.52-.25.42-2.86 3.89-2.86 6.31 0 1.28.48 2.34 1.34 2.98.75.56 1.74.73 2.64.46 1.07-.31 1.95-1.4 3.06-2.77 1.21-1.49 2.83-3.44 4.08-3.44 1.63 0 1.65 1.01 1.76 1.79-3.78.64-5.38 3.67-5.38 5.37 0 1.7 1.44 3.09 3.21 3.09 1.63 0 4.29-1.33 4.69-6.1h2.46'></path>
  </defs>
    <use id="a" xlink:href="#thePath" />
    <use id="b" xlink:href="#thePath" />
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

Если вы примените переменные CSS, то вы можете использовать только одну анимацию:

```css
use {
  stroke-dasharray: 1;
}
#a {
  --offset:0;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dashoffset: 53.66;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}
#b {
  --offset:1;
  stroke: DarkSeaGreen;
  stroke-dashoffset: 54.66;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: var(--offset)
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24' width="200"><title>gesture</title>
    <defs><path id="thePath"  fill="none" d='M4.59 6.89c.7-.71 1.4-1.35 1.71-1.22.5.2 0 1.03-.3 1.52-.25.42-2.86 3.89-2.86 6.31 0 1.28.48 2.34 1.34 2.98.75.56 1.74.73 2.64.46 1.07-.31 1.95-1.4 3.06-2.77 1.21-1.49 2.83-3.44 4.08-3.44 1.63 0 1.65 1.01 1.76 1.79-3.78.64-5.38 3.67-5.38 5.37 0 1.7 1.44 3.09 3.21 3.09 1.63 0 4.29-1.33 4.69-6.1h2.46'></path>
  </defs>
    <use id="a" xlink:href="#thePath" />
    <use id="b" xlink:href="#thePath" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to implement a continuous motion illusion in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56163505/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>